# AppDomain.Unload does not remove lock on dll

Tags: appdomain

am using the following code to create new AppDomain and load my assemblies into it, where my assemblies load successfully, but after i call the AppDomain.Unload method, there is still lock on the loaded dlls, where i went for creating new AppDomain solution because i found over the net that this is the recommended technique to load/unload assemblies and also to make the assemblies replaceable, any idea?

here is my code:

```
public sealed class AssemblyLoader : MarshalByRefObject
{
    private static AppDomain LocalDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("LocalDomain");

    public static Assembly LoadAssembly(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(path));
            if (assembly != null)
                return assembly;
        }
        catch { }

        return Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
    }

    public static void Unload()
    {
        if (LocalDomain != null)
        {
            AppDomain.Unload(LocalDomain);
            LocalDomain = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but from the theory shouldn't it be more like this.
You're not loading the assembly through the newly created AppDomain.

```
public static Assembly LoadAssembly(string path)
{
    try
    {
        Assembly assembly = LocalDomain.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(path));
        if (assembly != null)
            return assembly;
    }
    catch { }

    // ..
}
```

Comment: i tried your code where am facing this error:

Could not load file or assembly 'MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: i want to mention here that my assembly reside in another directory than bin.

Comment: You need to subscribe to the `AssemblyResolve` event. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx

Comment: am stuck !!!
i assigned the AssemblyResolve  event with no luck, still the same error, any recommendations?